# window.innerWidth usage in jQuery .css()

Tags: jquery, css, margins

I've got the following problem.
I want an interval to change the marginLeft of an element every 1 second
through jQuery. but this has to be the innerWidth of the window class divided by 4.

I have done it as following;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var adjust = setInterval(function() {
    $(".content").css("marginLeft" : window.innerWidth / 4);
}, 1000);
});
```

However the console just spits out the following error;

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How would you do this to make this work?

Thanks in advance, and I hope you out there can learn of this aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is wrong syntax: It should be either an `object literal` or use `comma`

```
$(".content").css({"margin-Left" : window.innerWidth / 4});
```

or

```
 $(".content").css("margin-Left" , window.innerWidth / 4);
```

Comment: Ah! such a stupid error.
Thanks alot for helping me out there.